# Screen tearing after suspension Mint

Tags: linux-mint, monitors

It is rather simple, whenever I put my machine to sleep and wake it up I always have slight tear, only in my main monitors right hand side of the monitor, around 10% is torn.

[image]

The only way to clear this is to restart.

Any ideas how to stop this?